# #import ProjectName-Swift.h into header file Can't use swift as .h property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I'm trying to use an @objc swift class as a property on my objective-c header file.

example

```
@objc class SwiftClass: NSObject {
}


@interface ObjcObject : NSObject

#pragma mark - Public Properties -
@property (nonatomic, weak) SwiftClass* swiftClass;
```

However if I `#import ProjectName-Swift.h` it gives me the error that "'ProjectName-Swift.h'file not found'

I found an answer here that implies you can't actually import Swift into a header file https://stackoverflow.com/a/29951314/3877767

How then am I supposed to use swift code together with objc code? I would not call swift and objc interoperable if you can't use @objc marked swift classes as properties on and objc header file

So inside of my `App-Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import "ObjcClass.h"
```

and inside of my `ObjcClass.h`

```
 #import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

This gives the error `ProjectName-Swift.h can't find file`

Either removing the `#import ProjectName-Swift.h`, or the `#import ObjcClass.h`fixes the problem, but then I can't use the Swift/OBJC code respectively

Comment: The problem was a cyclical reference. Forward declaring worked for classes, but haven't found a solution for protocols yet

Answer (score 0):

You don't import the header file. You give it to the compiler as a so-called "bridging header" that tells the compiler what to share between the two language environments.

You need to put your header file under the Objective-C Bridging Header as shown below:

[image: Xcode]

Comment: I'm sorry it may not have been clear, you do import class header files within the Bridging Header file. If I import this particular class .h file in the Bridging-Header.h file, and also import the -Swift.h file, it kills it but only if both of those things happen. If I don't do one or the other it works fine